# How best to model a complex function like Y=K^a*(cL+dM)^b (lowercase letters to be estimated)

Tags: regression, econometrics

Ok brains trust. I'm trying to model a production function which has an input that decays over 'distance' away from where production takes place.

In other words, an input that is 1 unit away is expected to have a greater effect on production than the otherwise identical input 2 units away.

This is really two problems: (1) estimating the production function and
(2) estimating the distance decay

If it were a cob douglas production function it might look like:

Y=K^a*(cL+dM)^b + error

Where 
the capital letters (K, L and M) are inputs
L and M are the same input, but L is one unit of distance away (effect c) and M is two units of distance away (effect d).

a,b,c and d are parameters to be estimated.

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on your model for the errors. Clearly you don't mean your equation *literally* as an equation - if it were true that Y was equal to the RHS you could take any 4 observations and get the same parameter estimates as any other 4. I assume some noise. If your errors were independent and additive with constant variance (which I imagine is highly unlikely) then you could use straight nonlinear least squares. If your errors were multiplicative you might take logs and fit a partially linear nls model. If the conditional distribution of Y behaved in some other way you might do something else

Comment: -- perhaps a generalized nonlinear model, for example. What sort of a variable is Y? Is it a monetary quantity or a count of items?

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, you're right, in practice it will be modeled on a sample, so there is an error term. Y is output as approximated by gross sales less tax (in $).